# Mocking, Unit Testing (NUnit) setup problem with HttpHandler

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, mocking, moq, httphandler

This post relates to two other posts, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518851/construtor-setter-injection-using-ioc-in-httphandler-is-it-possible) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551709/using-ioc-container-as-a-service-locator-for-httphandler).

I'm new to Unit Testing & Mocking. I have a test fixture that is trying to mock a HttpContext object including the response and request. I think the test code is not setup properly, as after calling the handler I get an error immediately. There error I am getting is:

UnitTests.UADHandlerFixture.Request_Is_Object:
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at Abstract.BaseHttpHandler.get_Request() in BaseHttpHandler.cs:line 21

at Abstract.BaseHttpHandler.get_IsRequestFromUAD() in BaseHttpHandler.cs:line 23

at Handlers.UADTimeHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context) in UADTimeHttpHandler.cs:line 19

at UnitTests.UADHandlerFixture.Request_Is_Object() in UADHttpHanderTests.cs:line 47

The test code is this:

```
    [TestFixture]
public class UADHandlerFixture
{
    private Mock<HttpContextBase> _mockHttpContext;
    private Mock<HttpRequestBase> _mockHttpRequest;
    private Mock<HttpResponseBase> _mockHttpResponse;
    private UADTimeHttpHandler _handler;
    private WindsorContainer _container;

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        _mockHttpRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        _mockHttpResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        _mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        _container.AddComponent<ILogger, FakeLogger>();
        _container.AddComponent<IDataRepository, FakeDataRepository>();

        _mockHttpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Application[0]).Returns(_container);
        _mockHttpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(_mockHttpRequest.Object);
        _mockHttpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(_mockHttpResponse.Object);

        _handler = new UADTimeHttpHandler();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Request_Is_Object()
    {
        _handler.ProcessRequest(_mockHttpContext.Object);
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
    public class UADTimeHttpHandler : BaseHttpHandler
{
    public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        if (IsRequestFromUAD)
        {
            Logger.Log("Log stuff");
            DataRepository.Write("DB stuff");
            ReturnResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        else
            ReturnResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

BaseHandler:

```
public abstract class BaseHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private HttpContext _httpContext;
    private ILogger _logger;
    private IDataRepository _dataRepository;
    protected ILogger Logger { get { return _logger; } }
    protected IDataRepository DataRepository { get { return _dataRepository; } }
    protected HttpContext Context { get { return _httpContext; } }
    protected HttpRequest Request { get { return _httpContext.Request; } }
    protected HttpResponse Response { get { return _httpContext.Response; } }
    protected bool IsRequestFromUAD { get { return Request.UserAgent == null ? false : Request.UserAgent.Equals("UAD"); } }
    public virtual bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        WindsorContainer container = (WindsorContainer)context.Application[0];
        _logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
        _dataRepository = container.Resolve<IDataRepository>();

        _httpContext = context;
        ProcessRequest(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
    }

    protected virtual void ReturnResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatus)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)httpStatus;
    }

    protected virtual void ReturnResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatus, string response)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)httpStatus;
        Response.Write(response);
    }

    protected virtual string GetInputStream()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    public abstract void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context);
}
```